# UICollectionView Vertical showing half the cell in the end

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

i have collectionView. it shows cell in vertically.

in the start the collectionView looks like this

[start of the collectionview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLHCB.jpg)
[image]

at the end it looks like this

[end of collectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56XKa.jpg)
[image]

so it basically doesnt show up the whole cell in the end
the code for collection class is

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - CollectionView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 9;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ViewControllerCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: are you using imageview in cell?

Comment: and the image you are showing in imageview is provided by coding?

Comment: No i have defined it in the IB @Abhi

Comment: did you check my answer working or not?

Comment: I have figured out what actually happened its because i have a navigation bar embedded @Abhi

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the cell size in your storyboard.

Comment: I dont get what you mean i obviously have done that. please mind me i am fairly new to iOS Development

Comment: there is two ways to specify the layout of your UICollectionView: 
1- On your storyboard, select the CollectionView then choose the 'Show the size inspector' (it looks like a ruler and is on the top right of your screen). Maybe you have to change the cell size.
2- Your delegate should inherit UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and return the size of your cell by implementing collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize (thats the method in swift, it must be similar in Objective C)

Comment: One sec, you're saying that you have a problem with the last cell only? If yes, that definitely means that you have problems in your collection view Constraints. Make sure that your collection view fit the parent view. 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have figured out what actually happened its because i have a navigation bar embedded @Najj

Answer (score 1):

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
float width = 100;  //change to your needed width
float height = 100;  //change to your needed height

return CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

}

Comment: is it because i am using a third party as my Flow layout.

Comment: I have figured out what actually happened its because i have a navigation bar embedded

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will help you

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 9;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

and change identifier name in attribute inspector as shown in image:

[image]

Comment: it's still the same.

Comment: but i tried the same code it displays correct image